# Vb.net Regex-remove html tags from string

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net, code-behind

```
 <br style="color: #252525">testing 1</br>
 <span style="color: font-family: Verdana">testing 2</span>



Dim RegExStr As String = "</?span.*?>"
```

it should remove complete span without text but i want to remove only style.

```
 <br>testing</br>
 <span>testing 2</span>
```

pls help to solve this,

Comment: Rule 1, don't parse HTML with RegEx. Rule 2, if you want to use RegEx to parse HTML, see Rule 1

Comment: How are you using this regex?

Comment: If only you knew that the HTML was always going to be well-formed XML, this would be a great application for XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

Freefaller already said the most important rule: Do not use RegEx to manipulate Html. Some great minds developed the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for us, which does the job way better and far more readable then RegEx ever could.

I am not capable of VB.net but the code would look similar to this:

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span"))
{
  node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
}
```

For a far more comprehensive overview on HtmlAgilityPack articles visit:
[How to use HTML Agility pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack)

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex to replace

```
(?<=<span[^<>]+)style="[^"]*"(?=[^<>]+>)|</span[^<>]*>
```

Though you should use an html parser or you can also interact with the DOM and remove the style..Depends on your requirements and what you are creating